# Showing a function is continuous(real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

[image]

Hello, I'm struggling showing that this function g(x) is continuous.  I've proved before that the composition of two questions, g o f is continuous and this question slightly reminds me of that.  I was thinking of maybe showing that preimages of open sets in g(x) are open sets or should I instead use the fact that a function is continuous that if pn converges to p then g(pn) converges to g(p)? Or I could use the epsilon delta definition of continuity?  I could really use any help, guidance, and suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What definition of continuity do you use?

Comment: We've discussed all three definitions of continuity.  I think the topological definition using open sets is the most common.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that the preimage of any open interval $(a,b)$ under $g$ is open. This is equivalent to showing that the preimages of both $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ are open.

Now if $g(x)>a$, then we must have $f(x,y)>a$ for some $y$.  From here it is easy to show that $g(x')>a$ for all $x'$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Now if $g(x)<b$, then you must have $f(x,y)<b$ for all $y\in [0,1]$. So for each $y\in [0,1]$there exists an open neighborhood $U_y$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ such that $f(x',y')$ for all $x'\in U_y$ and all $y'\in V_y$. By compactness of $[0,1]$, finitely many $V_y$ cover $[0,1]$. Let $U$ be the finite intersection of the corresponding $U_y$. Show that $f(x',y)<b$ for all $x'\in U$ and all $y\in[0,1]$.

---

Here is an alternative proof of the second part using sequences. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $g(x)<b$, but that there is no neighborhood of $x$ such that $g(x')<b$ for all $x'$ in the neighborhood. Then there is for all $n$ some $x_n\in B_{1/n}(x)$ and some $y_n$ such that $f(x_n,y_n)\geq b$. There is a subsequence $\langle y_{n_m}\rangle$ of the sequence $\langle y_n\rangle$ such that $\langle y_{n_m}\rangle$ converges to some $y\in [0,1]$. Use continuity of $f$ to show that $f(x,y)\geq b$ and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without compactness, we haven't covered that yet?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you prove that every sequence with values in $[0,1]$ has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes we proved that.

Comment: And we proved that the subsequence and the sequence converge to the same limit.

Comment: Imean, did you prove that even a nonconvergent sequence with values in $[0,1]$ has a subsequence that converges?

Comment: I don't think we proved that.

Comment: @BOB I seriously doubt that you can solve the problem then with what you learned so far.

Comment: We did prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem which states that every bounded sequence in R^n has a convergent subsequence.  Is this a useful fact for the question?

Comment: You may be right, we may not have learned enough to solve the problem. I'll clarify, thank you.

Comment: Yes. And a sequence with value in $[0,1]$ is clearly bounded and must therefore have a convergent subsequence. This subsequence must cnverge to a point in $[0,1]$. So this is enough.

Comment: Hi, I was going over this: slightly confused, by: "From here it is easy to show that g(x′)>a for all x′ in a neighborhood of x."  I'm not sure how this is easy to show and what x' means in your notation.

Comment: You have to show there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that for every point $x'$, $g(x')>a$.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but how would I begin a proof of this fact?  This doesn't seem so obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.  You will also want to use the fact that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is compact, so $f$ is not just continuous but uniformly continuous.  As a starting point, using uniform continuity of $f$, can you prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $g(x')\geq g(x)-\epsilon$ whenever $|x'-x|<\delta$?

A stronger hint is hidden below:

> Let $y$ be such that $f(x,y)=g(x)$.  What does the uniform continuity of $f$ then tell you when you apply it at the point $(x,y)$?

Comment: Hello, for some reason we skipped compactness and we won't be covering that until next week.